# Java, Data encapsulation, creating and destroying objects, StringTokenizer

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I am trying to read in a .txt file. Per 5 lines of text I want to get information from two of them, and store it in a class called Item, and then for the next five lines do the same.

And after each 5th line save that Item object in a temp object called Inventory that holds a linked list of Item objects.

I then pass this temp to a function that updates a master list accordingly.

So how can I go about doing this using, string tokenizer? I already have something implemented, code below is barebones/pseudocode. In the code there is a question, it is my main question.

InvObject has a linked list of Item objects.

CODE:

```
        InvObject temp = new InvObject();

        int i = 0;
        Item holdIt = null;

        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            i %= 5;

            if(i == 3 || i == 4)
            {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer tkner = new StringTokenizer(line);

                if(i == 3)
                {
                    int z = 0;
                    Item it = new Item();
                  while (tkner.hasMoreTokens())
                    {
                        String token = tkner.nextToken("$");
                        if(z == 1) // 2nd token of 3rd line is price
                            {it.pric = token;}
                        z++;
                    }
                    holdIt = it; // save item in a globaler variable
                }

                if(i == 4)
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    while (tkner.hasMoreTokens())
                    {
                        String token = tkner.nextToken("\t");
                        if(j == 2)
                            {holdIt.itemNum = token;}
                        j++;
                    }
                    temp.addItem(holdit);
                                delete(holdit);       //// Will this delete holdit from temps linked list?
                                                      /// Or does the linked list in temp copy the data to 
                                                      ///itself regardless of what happens to holdit
                    System.out.println(holdit.print());
                } 
            }
            i++;

        }
        in.close();
        UpdateItems(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to ask here, but, based on the comments on your code, the answer is no, deleting an object in java will have no effect on the list.

I'm not that sure what `delete(holdIt)` means though, if you want to remove and object you can either assign it a null value or call the default constructor `holdIt = new Type()`. In both cases the garbage collector will erase the old object from memory eventally.

If this is not the answer you were looking for please provide more information on what you want to achieve.